My disk space in Ubuntu doesn't reflect the actual disk space
I've got a problem with my Ubuntu install. I've got 500GB on my SSD, but Disk Usage Analyzer say I have 141.9GB.
When I type command like lsblk it shows me the right space, how can I fix this?
Results of df -h:
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
tmpfs              1,5G     26M  1,5G   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2     468G    433G   12G  98% /
tmpfs              7,5G     78M  7,4G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5,0M     12K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs           128K     23K  101K  19% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p1     1,1G    6,2M  1,1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs              1,5G    140K  1,5G   1% /run/user/1000

Results of lsblk:
    NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0  98,1M  1 loop /snap/bitwarden/120
loop2         7:2    0  35,2M  1 loop /snap/cheese/40
loop3         7:3    0  55,7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2829
loop4         7:4    0  55,4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2846
loop5         7:5    0  63,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2318
loop6         7:6    0    64M  1 loop /snap/core20/2379
loop7         7:7    0  74,3M  1 loop /snap/core22/1612
loop8         7:8    0  74,2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1621
loop9         7:9    0  66,2M  1 loop /snap/core24/490
loop10        7:10   0 115,5M  1 loop /snap/discord/211
loop11        7:11   0 115,5M  1 loop /snap/discord/212
loop12        7:12   0 271,6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/5014
loop13        7:13   0 272,1M  1 loop /snap/firefox/5134
loop14        7:14   0  10,7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop15        7:15   0  11,1M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/147
loop16        7:16   0 210,7M  1 loop /snap/gaming-graphics-core22/166
loop17        7:17   0   193M  1 loop /snap/gaming-graphics-core22/184
loop18        7:18   0 164,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
loop19        7:19   0 505,1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop20        7:20   0 406,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-46-2404/48
loop21        7:21   0   1,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/186
loop22        7:22   0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop23        7:23   0 437,3M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20/7
loop24        7:24   0 289,8M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/35
loop25        7:25   0   444M  1 loop /snap/kf5-5-113-qt-5-15-11-core22/1
loop26        7:26   0     2G  1 loop /snap/kf6-core22/38
loop27        7:27   0     2G  1 loop /snap/kf6-core22/39
loop28        7:28   0 211,5M  1 loop /snap/mesa-2404/143
loop29        7:29   0  56,9M  1 loop /snap/mumble/1731
loop30        7:30   0 182,5M  1 loop /snap/postman/283
loop31        7:31   0 182,4M  1 loop /snap/postman/286
loop32        7:32   0  89,1M  1 loop /snap/raindrop/25
loop33        7:33   0  10,5M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1173
loop34        7:34   0  38,8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
loop35        7:35   0  10,7M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1218
loop36        7:36   0   564K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/247
loop37        7:37   0   568K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/253
loop38        7:38   0 200,9M  1 loop /snap/steam/200
loop39        7:39   0 149,9M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/526
loop40        7:40   0 149,9M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/532
loop41        7:41   0 321,1M  1 loop /snap/vlc/3777
loop42        7:42   0  98,9M  1 loop /snap/bitwarden/122
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 475,9G  0 part /

Disk Analyzer:

Results of sudo du -hxd1 /:
203M    /boot
106G    /home
4,0K    /cdrom
11G /usr
4,0K    /lib.usr-is-merged
4,0K    /sbin.usr-is-merged
132K    /snap
4,0K    /srv
16K /lost+found
958M    /opt
313G    /var
8,0K    /media
36M /root
220K    /tmp
4,0K    /mnt
16M /etc
4,0K    /bin.usr-is-merged
434G    /

Results of mount :
    sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=7800788k,nr_inodes=1950197,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1567284k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=271)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap on /snap/bare/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bitwarden_120.snap on /snap/bitwarden/120 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bitwarden_122.snap on /snap/bitwarden/122 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2829.snap on /snap/core18/2829 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/cheese_40.snap on /snap/cheese/40 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2846.snap on /snap/core18/2846 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_2318.snap on /snap/core20/2318 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_2379.snap on /snap/core20/2379 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_1612.snap on /snap/core22/1612 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_1621.snap on /snap/core22/1621 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core24_490.snap on /snap/core24/490 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/discord_211.snap on /snap/discord/211 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/discord_212.snap on /snap/discord/212 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_5014.snap on /snap/firefox/5014 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_5134.snap on /snap/firefox/5134 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firmware-updater_127.snap on /snap/firmware-updater/127 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firmware-updater_147.snap on /snap/firmware-updater/147 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gaming-graphics-core22_166.snap on /snap/gaming-graphics-core22/166 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gaming-graphics-core22_184.snap on /snap/gaming-graphics-core22/184 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_198.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_176.snap on /snap/gnome-42-2204/176 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-46-2404_48.snap on /snap/gnome-46-2404/48 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_186.snap on /snap/gnome-system-monitor/186 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20_7.snap on /snap/kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20/7 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-core18_35.snap on /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/35 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kf5-5-113-qt-5-15-11-core22_1.snap on /snap/kf5-5-113-qt-5-15-11-core22/1 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kf6-core22_38.snap on /snap/kf6-core22/38 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kf6-core22_39.snap on /snap/kf6-core22/39 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mumble_1731.snap on /snap/mumble/1731 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mesa-2404_143.snap on /snap/mesa-2404/143 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/postman_283.snap on /snap/postman/283 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/postman_286.snap on /snap/postman/286 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/raindrop_25.snap on /snap/raindrop/25 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_1173.snap on /snap/snap-store/1173 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_1218.snap on /snap/snap-store/1218 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_21759.snap on /snap/snapd/21759 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_247.snap on /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/247 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_253.snap on /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/253 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/steam_200.snap on /snap/steam/200 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/thunderbird_526.snap on /snap/thunderbird/526 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/thunderbird_532.snap on /snap/thunderbird/532 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_3777.snap on /snap/vlc/3777 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1567284k,mode=755,inode64)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snapd-desktop-integration.mnt type nsfs (rw)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1567284k,nr_inodes=391821,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/thunderbird.mnt type nsfs (rw)

UPDATE: So i finally found the problem, it was docker/overlay2
What i did to find this and fix it was =>
sudo -i
baobab

Then the disk analyzer showed me the problem with docker/overlay2 then i deleted all cache with docker builder prune

Please update your question with the output of 'df -h' and 'lsblk' !

edited with screenshot and command from terminal

Also add the output of sudo du -hxd1 / and mount, please

edited with the result of those commands
